# Javascript opening new window targeting a PDF

Tags: javascript, http-headers

I have a chained dropdown box that pieces together a download string from a group of strings...

e.g.

```
string1 = "a4";
string2 = "_landscape";
string3 = "_lovely";
string4 = ".pdf";

totalString = string1 + string2 + string3 + string4;
window.open(totalString);
```

This works a treat in FireFox, but in IE I get the following error on the original window (even though the PDF opens in a new window):

> 405 - HTTP verb used to access this
>   page is not allowed. The page you are
>   looking for cannot be displayed
>   because an invalid method (HTTP verb)
>   was used to attempt access.

I have a feeling that this is "Headers" based, but I'm not 100% sure - can anyone help?

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried adding using a full url, `window.open('http://localhost/' + totalString);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you are `POST`ing data from a HTML page.  I had a similar issue last week with posting data from Facebook to a HTML page and had the same error message.  Make sure that you don't have any `<form>` tags in your code or any `AJAX` posting data.

Comment: arrr, you are correct sir! I removed the `<form>` tag and added the `.click()` instead - works a treat. Cheers! - 7 minutes till acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

Try constructing the full URL with the format http://www.example.com/path/a4_landscape_lovely.pdf.